# Pentaho PDI Not getting multiple rows from SOAP call

Tags: soap, pentaho, pdi

i'm using Pentaho PDI 9.3 to retreive rows from a SOAP call using the **Web services lookup** step. So far everything is going great, but somehow i only get the first row. When i test it out in a SOAPUI i can see there should be 4 rows.

- So the first step is setting up the variables i need
- Second is calling the soap, which runs succesfully
- Third is getting the XML data into rows
- Last step is removing all unnecessary fields

[image]

So the code i got from XPath is done by copy/pasting the XML from the SOAPUI into the Content and let PDI generate it automatically.

This is the output i get when using SOAPUI (all private info changed to xxxxxxxxxxx):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getAansluitingenResponse xmlns="https://webservice.xxxxxxxxxxxx">
         <getAansluitingenResult>
            <call_id>getAansluitingen</call_id>
            <aansluitingen>
               <WebserviceAansluiting>
                  <meternummer>xxxxxxxxxxx</meternummer>
                  <telwerk>xxxxxxxxxxx</telwerk>
                  <adres>xxxxxxxxxxx</adres>
                  <postcode>xxxxxxxxxxx</postcode>
                  <plaats>xxxxxxxxxxx</plaats>
                  <soort_leveren>leveren</soort_leveren>
                  <type_meting>normaal</type_meting>
                  <ean_code>xxxxxxxxxxx</ean_code>
                  <eenheid>KWH</eenheid>
                  <uitlees_frequentie>5</uitlees_frequentie>
               </WebserviceAansluiting>
               <WebserviceAansluiting>
                  <meternummer>xxxxxxxxxxx</meternummer>
                  <telwerk>xxxxxxxxxxx</telwerk>
                  <adres>xxxxxxxxxxx</adres>
                  <postcode>xxxxxxxxxxx</postcode>
                  <plaats>xxxxxxxxxxx</plaats>
                  <soort_leveren>terugleveren</soort_leveren>
                  <type_meting>normaal</type_meting>
                  <ean_code>xxxxxxxxxxx</ean_code>
                  <eenheid>KWH</eenheid>
                  <uitlees_frequentie>5</uitlees_frequentie>
               </WebserviceAansluiting>
               <WebserviceAansluiting>
                  <meternummer>xxxxxxxxxxx</meternummer>
                  <telwerk>xxxxxxxxxxx</telwerk>
                  <adres>xxxxxxxxxxx</adres>
                  <postcode>xxxxxxxxxxx</postcode>
                  <plaats>xxxxxxxxxxx</plaats>
                  <soort_leveren>leveren</soort_leveren>
                  <type_meting>controle</type_meting>
                  <ean_code>xxxxxxxxxxx</ean_code>
                  <eenheid>KWH</eenheid>
                  <uitlees_frequentie>5</uitlees_frequentie>
               </WebserviceAansluiting>
               <WebserviceAansluiting>
                  <meternummer>xxxxxxxxxxx</meternummer>
                  <telwerk>xxxxxxxxxxx</telwerk>
                  <adres>xxxxxxxxxxx</adres>
                  <postcode>xxxxxxxxxxx</postcode>
                  <plaats>xxxxxxxxxxx</plaats>
                  <soort_leveren>terugleveren</soort_leveren>
                  <type_meting>controle</type_meting>
                  <ean_code>xxxxxxxxxxx</ean_code>
                  <eenheid>KWH</eenheid>
                  <uitlees_frequentie>5</uitlees_frequentie>
               </WebserviceAansluiting>
            </aansluitingen>
            <succes>true</succes>
         </getAansluitingenResult>
      </getAansluitingenResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Anyone that can help me with this :(

Answer (score 0):

So i exported the data to an XML File and used a seperate step.
If i use this Loop XPath `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[name()='getAansluitingenResponse']/*[name()='getAansluitingenResult']/*[name()='aansluitingen']/*[name()='WebserviceAansluiting']`

and this XPath for fields: `*[name()='soort_leveren']`
I get all rows.
But if i use the EXACT same Loop XPath and XPath in the step that gets the XML data from a field, it returns empty.

Anyone knows why this is happening and what i'm doing wrong?